# How do I pass a value from a service into the forRoot() of a module on bootstrap?

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass data that gets generated inside my `StateService` class as the config of a separate library module.

```
import { ThirdPartyIntegrationsModule } from 'third-party-integrations';
import { StateService} from './services/state.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ThirdPartyIntegrationsModule.forRoot({ deviceId: 'I want to use: StateService.deviceId' }),
        CommonModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        StateService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

I have tried creating a new instance of the stateservice then using the value - but it doesn't work:

```
import { StateService } from './services';
const state = new StateService();

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ThirdPartyIntegrationsModule.forRoot({ deviceId: state.trackingId }),
```